# Something stopping method resizing being called

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, indexing, iteration

This code runs through and "resizes" (meaning transfers elements into bigger array) the array when I have `j=0` or `j=1` but it matches elements of the array against themselves therefore doesnt work properly
It only fills the array once and doesn't call the reSize method when `j=i+1` and when `i!=j`, can anyone shed some light because I know it's something simple....its driving me mad.

```
    private static String[] subStrings(String[] tokens) {
    String[] matches;
    matches = new String[40]; //creates a new array of matches 



    for (int i = 0; i <=tokens.length; i++){

        for (int j=i+1; j <tokens.length ; j++){


            if(Text.match(tokens[i],tokens[j])&&i!=j){

                if(matches[matches.length-1]!=null){
                    matches = reSize(matches, 10);
                }
                matches[i]=(tokens[i]+" | "+tokens[j]); 

                System.out.println(matches[i]);



            }
        }
    }
    return matches; //default return for compilation purposes
}

public static String[] reSize(String[] matches, int s){

    if(s<0){
        return null;
    }
    String BiggerMatches[] = new String[matches.length + s];


    for(int i=0; i< matches.length; i++){

        BiggerMatches[i]=matches[i]; 
    }

    matches=BiggerMatches;
      return matches;

}
```

Comment: Please give us a code that will compile and run out of the box. A snippet of code from a bigger project is a problem for us, too. Particularly what are tokens? What does the reSize() method do??

Comment: First of all, the boolean `i != j` is always true, because j starts at i + 1 and always increments. Other than that, I think your problem is in the statement `Text.match(tokens[i],tokens[j])` which I think is never true. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: It uses a method imported from another class to compare each element in the array to each other to find string & substring pairs. And it is true as it does find substrings, the only problems is it will consider for example "Sunday" as a substring of "Sunday"

Comment: As I see it, if `Text.match(tokens[i], tokens[j])` is false once, it is false always. You make no changes whatsoever in to any token. All changes are made into matches[]. Also, "Sunday" IS a substring of "Sunday". A string is always a substring of itself.

Comment: Tell me if it works. I'll make an answer out of that comment if it does.

Comment: Oh Ok it works fine if a string is considered a substring of itself, My problem was I thought it wasn't

Comment: If you want it so that it isn't, then just discard any matches where s1 equals s2